# Passing vectors by reference in C++ functions

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-reference

Freshman CS student here. I'm currently trying to write this project, which is a flexible to-do list using vectors. However, I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with the code.

It's supposed to select the function chosen by the user from the options menu function, and continue to ask the user to add things to the list unless they choose otherwise. The whole thing will end when the user chooses the "Done" option 7, and only after that's verified that there are no items left in the taskList array.

Here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void options()
{
  cout << "\nWhat to do?\n\n" << endl;

  cout << "1) Add to the list. \n";
  cout << "2) Show the next item on the list. \n";
  cout << "3) Do the next item on the list, and remove it. \n";
  cout << "4) List all items \n";
  cout << "5) Save list. \n";
  cout << "6) Load list. \n";
  cout << "7) All done with this To Do List! \n\n";
}

void addToList(vector<string>& vec) //add item to list
{
  string task;
  cout << "\nPlease add an item to the to-do list: ";

  getline(cin, task);
  vec.push_back(task);
} //addToList

void showNextItem(const vector<string>& vec) //display next item in list, do not remove it
{
  cout << "\nThe next item on the list is: ";
  cout << "==> " << vec.front();
} //showNext Item

void displayAllItems(const vector<string>& vec) //display all items in list
{
  cout << "\nHere's everything you still need to do: ";
  cout << "\n\n";

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << vec[i];
  } //for
} //displayAllItems

void doThis(vector<string>& vec) //display item, remove from list
{
  cout << "\nOK, time to do this list item: \n";
  cout << "==> " << vec.front();

  vec.erase(vec.begin());
} //doThis

void save(const vector<string>& vec) //asks user to input file name, saves all items to file
{
  string fileName;
  cout << "\nEnter file to save items: ";

  getline(cin, fileName);

  ofstream fout(fileName.c_str());
  fout.open(fileName);

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    fout << vec[i];
  } //for

  fout.close();

} //save

void load(vector<string>& vec) //asks user to input file name, loads items         from file and populates to do list with items
{
  string fileName;
  string line;
  cout << "\nEnter file to load to-do list: ";

  getline(cin, fileName);
  ifstream fin(fileName.c_str());

  fin.open(fileName);

  while (fin.good())
  {
    getline(fin, line);
    vec.push_back(line);
  } //while

  fin.close();

} //load

bool allDone() //displays goodbye message, exits
{
    bool done = true;
    cout << "\nAll done!";
    return done;
} //all done

int main()
{
  int option;
  bool done = false;
  string userOption;
  stringstream mystr;
  vector<string> taskList;

    options();
    cout << "==> ";
    getline(cin, userOption);
    mystr << userOption;
    mystr >> option;

    switch(option)
    {
      case 1:
        addToList(taskList);
        break;
      case 2:
        showNextItem(taskList);
        break;
      case 3:
        doThis(taskList);
        break;
      case 4:
        displayAllItems(taskList);
        break;
      case 5:
        save(taskList);
        break;
      case 6:
        load(taskList);
        break;
      case 7:
        allDone();
        break;
    } //switch
} //main
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: What isn't working properly, and how do you instead expect it to work?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AtlasC1: I expect for the user-entered option (int option) to select its corresponding function. 1 for addToList, 2 for showNextItem, etc. The problem is that when I run the code, only the first program addToList is executed, no matter which option is selected. I'm also trying to figure out a way to terminate the program when bool allDone is returned true, but only after there are no more items left in the vector.

Apologies if any of this has been unclear so far, still just starting to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new for this, and I find some suggestions for your program.

you can't choose other because you only run your switch part once. So I think you need `while` to continue get your input

1. I think the problem should not stop after choose the number once. So I think you may need a `while` or `for` for your choose part. And add a `return` at `case 7`.

   ```
   while(1)
   {
       options();
       cout << "==> ";
       getline(cin, userOption);
       option = atoi(userOption.c_str());
       switch(option)
       {
       case 1:
          addToList(taskList);
          break;
       case 2:
          showNextItem(taskList);
          break;
       case 3:
          doThis(taskList);
          break;
       case 4:
          displayAllItems(taskList);
          break;
       case 5:
          save(taskList);
          break;
       case 6:
          load(taskList);
          break;
       case 7:
          cout << "\nAll done!\n";
          return 0;
       default:
          return -1;
   }
   cout<<"\n========================"<<endl;
   ```

   }
2. when you save your data, you open your file twice, I think that's the reason you can't write your to your file. Of course, you need add some operator to separate your sentences in the file so that you can get that from file next time.
   The problem is also in your open part. You can open file just use this `ofstream fout(fileName.c_str(), ios::out);` without `open`. And if you use `while(fin.good())`, you may read one line more from your file. the code is:

   ```
   void save(const vecotr<string>& vec)
   {
       string fileName;
       cout <<"\nEnter file to save items: ";
       getline(cin, fileName);
       ofstream fout(fileName.c_str(), ios::out);

       for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
       {
          fout <<vec[i] << "\n";
       }
       fout.close();
   } 

   void load(vector<string>& vec) 
   {
       string fileName;
       string line;
       cout << "\nEnter file to load to-do list: ";

      getline(cin, fileName);
      ifstream fin(fileName.c_str());

      while(getline(fin, line))
      {
          vec.push_back(line);
      } //while
      cout <<"======" <<vec.size()<<endl;

      fin.close();
   }
   ```
3. two little thing is you may need to test the input word and in your display part you can add num in line to help user to read.

   ```
   void displayAllItems(const vector<string>& vec)
   {
        cout << "\nHere's everything you still need to do: ";
        cout << "\n\n";

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << i <<"."<< vec[i] << endl;
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: `atoi` is worse than OP's method because it causes undefined behaviour if the input is an integer out of range of `INT_MAX`. OP's code was fine except that he/she should check for failure and take action

Comment: Yes, this is just for basic function, I think for 0-7 `atoi` is enough. And For robustness of  program, we need to check users' input words. I think it's the questioner's need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
  fout << vec[i];
}
```

This will write the strings to the file, but not separate them by whitespace.

For example if the vector contains `{ "this", "is", "a test" }`, after the loop the file will contain `thisisa test`, not `this is a test` or `this\nis\na test`.

When you then try to read the contents of the file using `getline(fin, line)` it will only add one string to the vector, with the contents `"thisisa test"`.

To fix this, add a newline character to the file after `fout << vec[i]`:

```
fout << vec[i] << '\n';
```